# Transpose columns when multiple columns match

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to flatten the data I have as I'm getting multiple rows that largely contain the same data, it'll currently comes out looking like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
ABC  DEF  123  456  1    24
ABC  DEF  123  456  2    48
GHI  JKL  789  010  1    6
GHI  JKL  789  010  2    12
```

I want the output to be this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
ABC  DEF  123  456            24   48
GHI  JKL  789  010            6    12
```

This will be done based off of the value of column 5, if it's "1", the value of column 6 moves to column 7, if it's "2", it moves to column 8. This should only happen when the first columns are all matches as well.

Comment: So, you're never going to have more than two rows for each combination of `col1,col2,col3,col4`? `col5` is always going to contain 1 or 2?

Comment: @APC: I believe, we need to keep provision for flexible inputs. That's what, I have put in my solution !

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,null as col5, null as col6,
       max(case when col5=1 then col6 end) as col7,
       max(case when col5=2 then col6 end) as col8
from tablename
group by col1,col2,col3,col4
```

Comment: To give the Seeker's desired output, `null as col5, null as col6` rather than what you have.

Comment: Those columns aren't necessary on the output, I just put them in there for the visual indication that they were largely ignored after the processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution using `DECODE`:

```
WITH tbl AS(
  select 'ABC' as col1,'DEF' as col2,123 as col3,456 as col4,1 as col5,24 as col6 from dual union all
  select 'ABC','DEF',123,456,2,48 from dual  union all
  select 'GHI','JKL',789,010,1,6 from dual  union all
  select 'GHI','JKL',789,010,2,12 from dual 
)
select col1, 
       col2, 
       col3, 
       col4, 
       decode(min(col5), 1, null, min(col5)) as col5,
       decode(max(col5), 2, null, max(col5)) as col6,
       decode(min(col5), 1, min(col6), null) as col7,
       decode(max(col5), 2, max(col6), null) as col8
from tbl 
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
order by 1,2;
```

**Output:**
[image]